# How to extract and join files in Matlab

Tags: matlab, compression, zip, unzip

I have three files 1.zip, 1.z01 1.z02. I would like to extract and join them into a file. 
In Ubuntu command line I'm using `zip -FF name.zip --out name_joinde.zip`
I would like to do this in Matlab, but with the `zip` command I'm getting an `Invalid zip file` error. How can I joint this files?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it in one shot.  But it is easy to do systematically using the `zip` and `unzip` commands:

```
%% Unzip files into "tempdir" directory (will create the directory if needed)
unzip('MyFruits.zip', 'tempdir')
unzip('MyColors.zip', 'tempdir')

%% Zip all files in "tempdir" directory into Joined.zip
zip('Joined.zip', '*.*', 'tempdir')

%% Delete the "tempdir" directory and all of its subdirectories
rmdir('tempdir', 's')
```

Comment: I tried, but whit this function, I'm getting an `Invalid zip file` error

Comment: You have to use your own zip file names.  Which line in your case returns the error.  With `MyFruits.zip` and `MyColors.zip` files, which I created to zip a few MATLAB files, in my current MATLAB directory, I have confirmed that I can successfully merge them into the `Joined.zip` using the code in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the

> unzip(..)

command first, and then

> zip(..)

Answer (score 1):

How about just using `!` or `system` to call the Ubuntu command directly from within MATLAB?